# Django OneToOneField post_save cant call int object

Tags: django, django-models

I want to extend my 'User' model with the 'Profile' model. To facilitate this I've created the following model. I wanted to have the linked 'Profile' model be automatically created with each new 'User' model. Based on some comments on stackoverflow / research on the internet ([simpleisbetterthancomplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)) I came with the following solution:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')

    #Pushup related stats
    total_pushups = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    best_consecutive = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    week_streak = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    save = models.IntegerField(default=000)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

However, every time I run this (whether through unit tests or 'create superuser' - I have no vies yet, I'm practicing TDD) I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Does anyone here know what I am doing wrong?

**Edit: I've included a traceback of the error message that is shown after the 'create superuser' command**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 183, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 170, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 153, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 847, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/user_profiles/models.py", line 20, in create_user_profile
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/PushUpTuneUp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: We can't know unless you provide the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've added the full traceback of the error message that occurs after the 'create superuser'  command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a field called `save`, which is hiding the actual `save` method. Rename it to something else.

(And not related to your problem, but you certainly shouldn't have two receivers here. I can't see why you need the second one at all, but even if you did need that logic you should just put it in with the first one.)

Comment: Renaming the save variable solved the problem! 
Thank you!